# NoClassDefFoundError for resource in build path

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, build, ignite

I am trying to add add Apache Ignite to an existing CSV Project built with ant (none of these are things I have control over) in Eclipse.

I have added the following jars to the build path:

- cache-api-1.1.1.jar
- ignite-core-2.9.1.jar
- ignite-core-2.9.1-javadoc.jar
- ignite-core-2.9.1-sources.jar
- ignite-spring-2.9.1
- ignite-spring-2.9.1-javadoc
  -ignite-spring-2.9.1-sources

I can import what I need from Ignite in Eclipse and the project complies without error but when I go to start the complied application I get the following error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxx' defined in class path resource [yyyyy.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [xxxx]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/TcpDiscoveryIpFinder
....
caused by: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/TcpDiscoveryIpFinder

However in Eclipse, in the project explorer I can expand Referenced Libraries->ignite-core-2.9.1.jar and see spi.discovery/tcp/ipfinder/TcpDiscoveryIpFinder

As an added twist the class that failed to instantiate does not even use Ignite or the TcpDiscoveryIpFinder.

This process has worked in the past for adding things such as Mockito to the project, but not in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after thinking a bit more I realized I needed to add the ignite jars to apache-tomcat/lib.

This resolved the issue.

As for the reason this did not occur before with Mokito is all units tests are only run within Eclipse, not in the actual application.